# In Ubuntu 13.04, after the computer sleeps, I lose my wireless connection

Tags: wireless, networking, hibernate

After sleep or hibernation, the wireless icon shows no connection. When I click on it I see several wireless networks but not the one that I was connected before. When I click the "Edit networks..." I see the network that I used before. Currently the only solution is to reboot which makes the computer useless

Comment: After the computer wakes up from sleep, click on Network manager and un-check **Enable WiFi** wait 10 seconds and click on it again to put the check mark back on and thus enabling WiFi again. If this helps I will write it as an answer and you can accept it then.

Comment: check out this answer

[solution of Wild man worked for me][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/365112/lubuntu-13-10-laptop-loses-wireless-after-sleep

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lock screen after boot from suspend or hibernation? If so, I have found that if I login too quickly the connection is lost. The Wifi icon is visible on the lock screen. Wait until the icon shows you are connected to the wifi before logging in. It is usually only a couple of seconds wait time.