# Lubuntu 13.10 - Laptop Loses wireless after sleep

Tags: wireless, networking, lubuntu, laptop, 13.10

I'm running Lubunu 13.10 on an hp G62 - I'm new to Lubuntu having used ubuntu previously, but I've made the switch as my laptop is now getting toward the lower end of acceptability, and I'm delighted with how well it runs.

Anyway, I'm having an issue that if I close the lid of the laptop it won't reconnect to the wi-fi when I open it again, and I'm not sure how to even force it to scan for a network - I have to restart it at the moment - and then it always connects perfectly. The router is a BT Business Hub 2.

Any help much appreciated - thank you.

EDIT - at home it seems to re-connect with no issues to the router EE gave me - so it may be an issue to do with Lubuntu/the router at work.

Comment: For the time-being I have a text file on my desktop containing the following:

sudo nmcli nm sleep false
or
sudo killall NetworkManager
or
sudo restart network-manager
or
sudo nmcli nm sleep false

I've so far managed to get connected again using sudo nmcli nm sleep false

Answer (score 2):

Please do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

A new empty file will open. Add one line:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8192ce"
```

Of course, substitute your actual driver in place of rtl8192ce. Proofread, save and close gedit.
Reboot

If you do not know the name of your wireless driver run this command:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
```

it will tell you the device name for wireless and ethernet along with the driver being used for each.

Edit: Here is one last thing to try:

```
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh

sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Insert the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
nmcli nm sleep false
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
Save
```

This answer was found [on the forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182128&p=12830153#post12830153)

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've done as you suggest and am currently a the 'testing' phase - it didn't always fail to wake previously so I'm keeping an eye on it.

Just to add though that Lubuntu 13.10 doesn't come with gedit, so if you're hard-of-thinking like me it will take you a while to realise you need to type:

'sudo leafpad /etc/pm/config.d/config'

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Follow the directions in my answer from the where I wrote edit down to the last line in the answer. If it works please accept the answer so it will benefit everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Just so you are aware, there is a bug already filed about this issue and I have also confirmed that it affected my Toshiba Satellite.

[[logind] stuck in PrepareForSleep, causing network and other services to not resume Bug#1184262](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1184262)

One person also posted a temp solution that seems to work. After opening your lid and the network doesn't return, run:

```
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
```

I upgraded from Lubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 via update manager and started to have all these issues. Yesterday I backed up my data and did a fresh install (reformatted and installed). I am confirming today that this issue doesn't not happen anymore and a few others have "gone".

Comment: Thank you - this does restore connectivity, although it does also report various errors as it does so (but the laptop runs fine it seems)